# telnet: connect to address HostB: Connection refused

Tags: port, telnet, iptables, firewalld

I looked through the previous posts and didn't find an answer to my problem. Hope you don't mind helping!

**Issue:** When attempting to telnet from one host to another on port 8080, I am getting "telnet: connect to address HostB: Connection refused". On the other hand, I can telnet to several other ports.

```
[root@HostA bin]# telnet HostB 8080
Trying HostB-IP...
telnet: connect to address HostB-IP: Connection refused

[root@HostB ~]# lsof -i :8080
[root@HostB ~]# 

[root@HostB ~]# netstat -l | grep :8080
[root@HostB ~]#
```

iptables doesn't seem to be enabled or started

```
[root@hostB ~]# systemctl status iptables
iptables.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)

[root@hostB ~]# systemctl start iptables
Failed to issue method call: Unit iptables.service failed to load: No      such file or directory.

[root@hostB ~]# systemctl stop iptables
Failed to issue method call: Unit iptables.service not loaded.

[root@HostB ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

which I read was replaced by firewalld in CentOS 7(which I am using).

```
[root@hostB ~]# systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled)
Active: inactive (dead)

Mar 12 17:18:53 hostB systemd[1]: Starting     firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Mar 12 17:18:54 hostB systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Mar 12 17:22:45 hostB systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Mar 12 17:22:46 hostB systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

so it appears that both iptables and firewalld are not running, however, only some ports are opened. I've also tried adding iptable rules to accept port 8080.

```
[root@HostB ~]# netstat -l | grep :
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8191            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:irdmi           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:8065          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:smtp          [::]:*                  LISTEN     
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:24077           0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:40462           0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:bootpc          0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ntp             0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp        0      0 localhost:323           0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:mdns            0.0.0.0:*                          
 udp6       0      0 [::]:ntp                [::]:*                             
 udp6       0      0 localhost:323           [::]:*                             
 udp6       0      0 [::]:58833              [::]:*                             
 raw6       0      0 [::]:ipv6-icmp          [::]:*
```

**Question** - How do I determine what is allowing these ports and services besides iptables and firewalld as they appear to be disabled? Thanks!!

Comment: any help around?

Comment: on hostB try an `iptables -nvL` just to be sure that the policy is ACCEPT and no other firewall rules are active. Does the hostB server have a private ip address or a public ip?!